# Call a sub in Workbook_BeforeSave event

Tags: excel, vba

I want to call this Sub in the Workbook_BeforeSave event:

```
Sub test()
If ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "" Then
MsgBox ("Please fill in cell A4!")
Exit Sub
Else
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 test
End Sub
```

When I click save the file is saved even if the cell A4 is blank.

Comment: Is it possible that, on saving, the sheet you intended is by `ActiveSheet` is not actually the active one? Also, though it is a personal preference and not strictly necessary, using `Call` could help your code's readability

Answer (score 2):

You should set **Cancel** as the proper way to terminate the save event.
It would be better to have `test` as a function, so you can check the return value, and set cancel appropriately.

```
Function test() as Boolean
If ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "" Then
    Test = False
Else
    Test = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If test = False then Cancel=True
End Sub
```

Also, `ActiveSheet` is not appropriate, unless you have only one worksheet, and you have protected the workbook from having extra sheets added.
My suggested solution would be to check `Sheets("MySheet").Range("A4")`.

Of course, the laziest way to do the test would be:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
cancel = (ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "")
End Sub
```

where the test is done within the save procedure, and no sub tests are required.

Comment: or `Cancel= Not Test` :)

Comment: @brettdj, yes, I know. It was done for illustrative purposes. Check the edit for the quickest way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call test
End Sub

Sub test()
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please fill in cell A4!")
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

*Exit Sub* merely terminates sub test(), while *End* completely stops code execution, thus preventing Workbook_BeforeSave() from running further.

Answer (score 0):

if cancel is true, the saving will be blocked :

```
Sub Test(byref cancel as boolean)
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A4") = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please fill in cell A4!")
        cancel = true
        Exit Sub
    'Else
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Test Cancel
End Sub
```